# returning back to the same app after switching to map app

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4, ios-simulator

In my application I need to go to a particular place in the google map by hitting below url

```
 UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];  
 [app openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=<any place>"]];
```

I am not getting a way to come back again to the same screen.

Tell me how I will come back to the same app again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't go back automatically. Only the user can go back to your app if he decides to.